# Modify existing PDF file in browser

Tags: javascript, pdf, browser

Is there any JavaScript library that allows to modify PDF file on the client-side (I mean directly in web browser)? I would like to add an QR code into PDF which user puts into browser, but without sending to the server.

I have found https://github.com/galkahana/HummusJS, but it looks like it works only on the server-side in Node.js.

My temporary solution is to read and render PDF into Canvas via `https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js`. After that I simply render QR code and save/render result into PDF document via `https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF`.

This solution has flaw, because It just prints out an image into PDF. I need to keep the original format of the PDF and just add that QR code on some page in it.

Any suggestions would be help. Thanks.

Comment: I'm also looking for the same thing (adding signature image). I've rendered the pdf into SVG using the PDF.js library, then I successfully added the image, but I can not find the reliable library to convert back the updated SVG code to pdf.

Comment: Those to libraries might work for you
https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib
https://github.com/DevelopingMagic/pdfassembler

Comment: Hi, have you know the answer? i would like to know too